# What is the most efficient and correct way to save and store a record within a custom save funciton?

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Controller**

```
    public PageReference Save() {

        if (cardRequest != NULL) {

            insert cardRequest;

            PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + Business_Card_Request__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());

            pr.setRedirect(true);

            return pr;

        }

        return null;

    }
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
        <apex:pageBlockButtons id="businessCardRequestButtonSetOne">
            <apex:commandButton value="SAVE" action="{!Save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="CANCEL" immediate="true" html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate" action="{!Cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

I believe `cardRequest` is the culprit. When I click the save button on the `Visualforce Page`, the page will refresh and the record will not be saved.

Comment: Put a error handler and debug the save method,

Comment: Does your `save` button have a `rerender` attribute? It is your markup we need to see here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have an `<apex:commandButton>` tag and you do not specify a `rerender` attribute, the `action` will refresh the entire page. In the case of error handling for an extension, you would want to rerender an `<apex:pageMessages>` tag (or `<apex:messages>`, as you wish). The following pattern is common:

**Controller**

```
public PageReference save()
{
    PageReference redirect;
    // set to whatever you wish
    // I'd normally set it in the controller's constructor

    try
    {
        insert record; // e.g. cardRequest
        // if you wanted to redirect to the record view, use:
        // redirect = new ApexPages.StandardController(record).view();
    }
    catch (DmlException d)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(d);
        // now these error messages will show up in your pageMessages tag

        return null;
        // now you won't redirect anywhere
    }
    return redirect;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:pageMessages id="msgs" />

    <!-- intermediate markup -->
    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="msgs" />
    <!-- intermediate markup -->

</apex:page>
```